# Spinner onItemSelected(?????)

Tags: android, if-statement, spinner

the first spinner is ok, the second spinner is ArrayList, ArrayAdapter<> and it loads a folder of file names, so, im wondering how to use the if() like file name contains,or list item contains, because each of the files either starts with a 62 or a 31.

```
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3)
{
    switch(arg0.getId())
    {
    case R.id.spinner:
    {
    if(arg2 == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    if(arg2 == 1)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Inspector.this, hord.class);
        Inspector.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        break;
    }
    if(arg2 == 2)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Inspector.this, hord.class);
        Inspector.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        break;
    }
    }
    case R.id.recent:
    {
        if(arg1.getContentDescription().toString().contains("62"))//what im trying to do
        {
            deviation.setText("jobwelldone");
        }

    }
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: You need to explain this a bit better before we can help. Add some context and ask a clear question.

Comment: if the item selected contains "62"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have saved your filenames in a String array then you can iterate through the array using the for loop for example and use the

```
indexOf()
```

method that searches the calling String object for the String passed to it. For example:

```
( if filename.indexOf(String.valueOf(62)) == -1 )
```

// means that filename String doesn't contains '62' substrng because the indefOf() method returned -1. Otherwise filename String contains '62' substring.

To get an item from a spinner:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

or use:

```
String spinnerValue = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: but from the spinner using onItemSelected

Comment: so would filename be arg1, or arg0.getAdapter()something, thats what im trying to figure out

Comment: I have added the piece of code how to read a value from the spinner at given postion